# Can't get client to connect to server

Tags: python, sockets

I'm just very confused still about the basic socket process. Tried multiple ways to try and get the socket to connect but it keeps refusing.

client code- socket_client.py

```
import socket

host = socket.gethostname()
port = 8080

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((host,port))

res = client.send (b' testing data send...')
client.close()
```

server code- server_client.py

```
import socket


host   = socket.gethostname()
port   = 8080 
    
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((host, port))
server.listen(10)

x=0
server_data = []
while True:
    conn, addr = server.accept()  
    data = conn.recv(4096).decode()
    x += 1
    print ('Servicing client at %s'%addr[0])
    server_data = client.recv(4096)
    client_close()
server.close()
```

Comment: what's not working exactly? Can you add that information?

Comment: I'm getting a ConnectionRefusedError with client.connect((host, port))

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems in your server.  You read from the connection but never use it, and you do `client.recv` when there is no variable `client`.  This works:

```
import socket

host   = socket.gethostname()
port   = 8080 
    
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((host, port))
server.listen(10)

x=0
server_data = []
while True:
    conn, addr = server.accept()  
    x += 1
    print ('Servicing client at %s'%addr[0])
    data = conn.recv(4096).decode()
    print( "Received", data )
    conn.close()
server.close()
```

Do remember that Python has a SocketServer module that can make some of this easier.  If you need to get fancier, there are few modules better than Twisted at this kind of thing.

ALSO remember that the server must be running before you start the client.  Someone has to be listening, otherwise the connection is rejected.